# How to replace text in a p tag with the response body from an API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, json, html, function

I've got this Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#generator').on('click', function getQuote() {
      $('#quote').text("response body here")
  });
});
```

which currently works to replace the text in the p tag with "response body here", my next step in figuring this whole thing out is to figure out how to get the response body of an api endpoint in where "response body here" is. I've tried a couple things including

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#generator').on('click', function getQuote() {
      $.getJSON("https://...api", function(json) {
        $("#quote").text(JSON.stringify(json));
      });
  });
});
```

but whatever I do, if I try to put any function besides my original one, the button no longer generates any new text. I've verified the endpoint is valid even with no headers passed in via Postman, so it should be returning something, but I get nothing. Once I can return the response body here, I can figure out how to get the rest of it how I want it, this is just part of the rough out.

Comment: Are you sure the function passed to `getJSON` runs? (Does using the `fail` property tell you anything?)

Comment: I'm not entirely certain how to check that. I'm working in CodePen, and I'm fairly new to Javascript. Here's the pen if that helps: https://codepen.io/chase-hippen/pen/MVMQVz

Comment: Just `console.log('running')` or something right after the `$.getJSON` line. Can you post the API link you're trying to use so we can try to replicate and debug your issue?

Comment: It is not running. Here's the endpoint: https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=J.%20R.%20R.%20Tolkien&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&formatversion=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikiquote is on another domain, and it has CORS enabled, as almost all sites do, so it is not possible for you to (natively) make a network request to it from a browser. To get information from it, you'll have to use your own backend, or relay off of someone else's backend:

```js
$('#generator').on('click', () => {
  fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=J.%20R.%20R.%20Tolkien&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&formatversion=2")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(responseObj => $("#quote").text(JSON.stringify(responseObj)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="generator">generator</div>
<div id="quote">quote</div>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "use your own backend, or relay off of someone else's backend", do you just mean using the fetch function?

Comment: I mean, use your own server to relay the request, or use someone else's server to relay the request. You *need* to utilize a backend of some sort. In the snippet, if you read the code, you'll see that I'm using `cors-anywhere` to achieve that.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! I did a bit of research on HerokuApp, and this will be very useful in the future.